# Problems about making upgraded win10 images

Tags: windows-10

I have a PC with win 7 activated by volume license. After upgrading to win10. I want to use this as the source to make images with ghost. In the future, when I restore the image to a bunch of new PCs, will the win10 images be activated successfully? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, images restored to different PCs would need to be activated individually with the appropriate license(s).

Windows 10 activation is tied to the hardware, and restoring an image to a different PC is equivalent to a complete hardware change. From Microsoft's [Activation in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation):

> - Activating Windows 10 after a hardware configuration change
>
>   If you upgraded to Windows 10 using the free upgrade offer and then made significant hardware changes to your device, such as replacing the motherboard, Windows 10 might no longer be activated.

It's not entirely clear how this applies to a Windows 7 VL (volume license) upgraded via the free upgrade offer, and it may depend on whether there is an active/ongoing agreement or subscription.

Comment: I have tried to put the win10 upgraded hard disk to another PC. It asked me to activate the 10 again. I just inputted the win7 volume key used before and activated successfully.